# How to make some django form fields depend on the value of other fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that requires some fields only if a radio button is selected.

If i set the field as "required=True" then it behaves has desired, but how do I get it to behave as "required=False" when the radio button is not selected?

I'm thinking I'd go for a default of `required=False` then check the value of the radio button in `form.clean()` and call for a `clean_<field>` for those fields that are now required, but it doesn't seem to be that simple. Or is it?

Alternatively I'd start with `required=True`, then in `form.clean()` check the value of the radio button, and if not set then just remove any errors raised from the no-longer-required fields?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, looky, I worked it out all by my lonesome... the latter option is indeed much simpler than trying to find and call validation routines on specific fields. Much easier to squash the errors:

Set all the potentially required fields as `required=True` then in `form.clean()` test the value of the other field and, if necessary, just delete the errors from `self.errors`

```
# payment type
payment_method = forms.CharField(max_length="20", required=True)
payment_method.widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES)

# credit card details
cc_number = CreditCardField(max_length=20, required=True)
cc_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
cc_expiry = ExpiryDateField(required=True)
cc_ccv = VerificationValueField(required=True)

def clean(self):
    data = super(PaymentForm, self).clean()
    if data.get('payment_method') == 'paypal':
        for field_name in ['cc_number','cc_name','cc_expiry','cc_ccv']:
            if field_name in self.errors:
                del self.errors[field_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

`form.clean` is the right place to do this.  What's not right is calling `clean_<field>` for other fields - they will have already been cleaned and their values will be in the `cleaned_data` dict.

Take a look at the example in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other
It runs through almost exactly this scenario, showing how you can test one field based on another and how you can either raise a form-level error when missing or bind the error to one of the fields.